# How to run lstm algorithm faster to send result to client side

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, lstm

I have datasets about 100 and each dataset has about 3000 item and I want to get prediction with lstm algorithm for next 2 month with using last 300 item foreach dataset after that I want to trigger this prediction from client(not for all datasets just 1 dataset) side.When user want to see some prediction, Client will send as an parameter name dataset and python script runs lstm algorithm and create some prediction for 1 dataset and send to client.My senario is something like this.But when I run this python script , it takes a long time to work.I need to run it faster.Do you have any suggestion also you can change my senario.But most important point that I need to Show some prediction to client in some minutes for just 1 dataset.I'm open to all kinds of suggestions.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use numpy arrays, they are much faster better at dealing with large blocks of memory than the standard python lists.

`import numpy as np`

[numpy documentation can be found here](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: I have alreay used it in python when I read dataset but my question for lstm because lstm Works with long time